# How to set label on secret created by ServiceAccount?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Is there any way to set label on secret created by ServiceAccount? For now it is the only secret I'm not able to configure with label.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: forum-sa
```

[image]

Comment: It would probably be overkill, but you might use a MutatingWebhook for that

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below configuration using the service account with kubectl,Follow the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-management/2.0.0?topic=kubectl-using-service-account-tokens-connect-api-server#kube)[1](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-management/2.0.0?topic=kubectl-using-service-account-tokens-connect-api-server#kube)

kubectl get secret --namespace={namespace}

By using above kubectl command which will help to set label namespace for secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Using the service account token with kubectl:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-management/2.0.0?topic=kubectl-using-service-account-tokens-connect-api-server

We can patch the secrets label with the required labels or we can also add the labels during secrets creation

Comment: Hmm I'm still not sure how exactly I can set this label. I have my deployment definition in yaml files (they are build by kustomize). Where exactly I have to apply the patch to set label in the created token? I tried set label in ServiceAccount but this label is not set in token

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).